# On Apple TV, What does signing in with my TV provider and allowing apps to access the subscription actually do?

Tags: appletv

I thought the idea was that i could go into the Apple TV settings app and sign in with my TV provider, so that I would not need to sign into into apps individually.

What i find is that even after an app asks for permission to access my TV subscription, I am still required to go to another device, navigate to a URL, and sign in with my TV provider password.

Is this working right?

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207035):

According to Apple, not all providers or apps support single sign-on. As you've already discovered, sometimes you need to sign-in to an app separately.  This isn't just with Apple TV; I have a Roku and it does the same thing.

Normally, I would paste the names of the TV providers and apps that support SSO.  However, this list is very long and often changes so posting them here doesn't make sense.  Instead, I'll post the links to Apple's site that contain the lists.  That way, it should always be up-to-date.

- [List of TV providers that support SSO](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208084)
- [List of apps that support SSO](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208085)

Here's how to see a list of supported apps by provider on your Apple TV:

1. Open the App Store.
2. Choose the Featured tab.
3. Scroll down and look for either an icon called TV Providers or an icon of your specific TV provider. Select the icon to see apps that support single sign-on. The list of supported apps might update as apps add support for single sign-on.

Comment: these are apps that are requesting to use my sign on, so they seem to support SSO.

Comment: According to Apple, if they don't work you need to contact the vendor.  Apple doesn't make the apps so they can't troubleshoot them.